# matplotlib, geopandas: transforming coordinates with transData.transform -> different results when running vs debugging?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

The below code results in

```
1909.090909090909
```

However, if I put a breakpoint on the last two lines of code:

```
t=ax[0,0].transData.transform((axisLimits[1],0))[0]
print(t)
```

run a debug and query the variables after going step by step to the last line, it shows a different result in the debugger - and sadly that one is the correct one. Why?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(40, 40))

dummyPoly = Polygon([[800, 800],[800,-800],[-800,-800]])

dummyGDF = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], geometry=[dummyPoly], crs='EPSG:4326')

ax[0,0] = dummyGDF.plot(ax=ax[0,0])
axisLimits=ax[0,0].axes.get_xlim()
t=ax[0,0].transData.transform((axisLimits[1],0))[0]
print(t)
```

Comment: Why assigning your plot to your axis `ax[0,0] = dummyGDF.plot(ax=ax[0,0])`?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know but now I will do some more reading and learning. Thanks for the pointer @s.k (do you think it could be related to the problem I described?)

Comment: No I don't think so, because they are the same object in memory (so the operation is normally useless) : `ax[0,0] is dummyGDF.plot(ax=ax[0,0]) # True`. But this tutorial may help you: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html

Comment: Try with a more reasonable sized figure.  Your figure manager is probably shrinking your maximum window size to fit your screen and this is happening at a different time for the debug run versus the free run. But mre to the point, what are you trying to accomplish?  You should rarely need the pixel co-ordinates of anything in Matplotlib.

Comment: Thank you,  I stumbled across this problem when I tried to calculate the scale of a map I am cutting on a laser. So, I do need the pixel/dpi=inches to find the real scale of the map - no? I trimmed down the code to the example here to make it easy to replicate. Is there a easy way to find the scale of a plot? The problem behind the problem is that the size of the plot changes with the padding etc so I can really only calculate the scale once the resizing of the plot is done - but I need the scale before I produce the plot...It feels like there may be a much easier solution,  just not seeing it

Comment: I can't say I understand, but I found a solution: I ultimately save the figure as an SVG file - once I have plotted everything. If I save an additional copy before I calculate the scale as per above question, but after the whole subplot layout is defined - then it give the correct result. My sense is that matplotlib assumes some sort of output method like a screen with a certain size etc - that obviously affect the real life scale of the figure. Once I save it as an SVG file I assume matplotlib takes that for the calculations. Not exactly a scientific explanation, but it works for now..